# How to show table data in react javascript from a list of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am following some tutorials on youtube, he is showing data succesfully but it is hard coded data, and I want to take data from backend. Data is coming successfully(I see it on console with console.log) but I could not show in table.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as service from '../service/FetchCustomerService';

function MainPanel() {

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostList = async () => {
      const response = await service.getCustomerList();
      setCustomers({ response });
      console.log(response.data)
    };
    fetchPostList()
  }, [setCustomers]);

  return (
    <ReactBootStrap.Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {customers &&
            customers.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.firstName}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </body>
      </ReactBootStrap.Table>
  );
}

export default MainPanel;
```

Here is async service method to get data:

```
export async function getCustomerList() {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/customer/list");    
}
```

Backend is returning 5 data in a list successfully but I could not show it on table.
In example console output is that first printing the list successfully and then

```
Uncaught TypeError: customers.map is not a function
    at MainPanel (MainPanel.js:29:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:20313:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22356:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
```

How can I show the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get result from API by `response.data` when using `axios`.

You don't need to add `setCustomers` (React `setState` function) because it is created by `useState`.

According to React documentation,

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostList = async () => {
      const response = await service.getCustomerList();
      setCustomers(response.data);
      console.log(response.data)
    };
    fetchPostList()
  }, []);
```